# How to check if all the mathematics in the LaTex document is in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

Is there a quick way to check if all the mathematics in the LaTeX document is in math mode?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  "Mathematics" is whatever is in math mode.  How do you (not TeX) tell if you have mathematics that is not in math mode?  Or are you talking about single variables, like did you use a bare "x" that should be in math mode?

Comment: You should get warnings is you put things like \alpha or \sqrt in text mode.  My TeX editor highlights math mode in green (alas, also TikZ calc notation).  Ultimately you will need to proofread it.

Comment: latex can not warn you if `x` or `1` are in text  when they should be in math you would need to search with your editor or a commandline search with grep or perl or similar

Comment: If you use anything in text mode that should be in math mode (e.g., `\sum`) you will face a "Missing $ inserted" error, so the check is done. If you insert something in text mode that could be perfectly in text mode , as "x", or  "1", or "2+2=22", LaTex cannot check that you have in mind, but you can check the output too see if the font is the wrong one  ("x"),  or the spacing is wrong ("2+2=22"). In the case of "1" the output is identical  anyway (with the default math font), so who cares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an editor that will highlight TeX syntax for you and display math mode in a different color.

The `\(`, `\)`, `\[` and `\]` delimiters are less prone to accidental mismatching than `$` and `$$`.  The compiler will catch if you forget to open or close one of them.  Switching to the paired versions is best practice.